# How to re-sort an indexed array of associative arrays, based on the values in the associative arrays?

Tags: arrays, bash, multidimensional-array, associative-array

In my shell code, I have an indexed array, containing the names of associative arrays:

```
declare -A assoc1=([name]=aaa [age]=20)
declare -A assoc2=([name]=bbb [age]=40)
declare -A assoc3=([name]=ccc [age]=25)
indexed_array=(assoc1 assoc2 assoc3)
```

So, using the above, `${indexed_array[@]}` equals `assoc1 assoc2 assoc3`.

I want a `sort_array` function that can re-sort the values in  `indexed_array`, so that the associative array with the highest age (assoc2) is listed first or last, like so:

```
new_indexed_array=( $(echo ${indexed_array[@]} | sort_by 'age' 'desc') )
```

After that I should get re-ordered contents in the new array:

```
declare -p new_indexed_array
# gives "assoc2 assoc3 assoc1"
```

I have some boilerplate code to get into the array values, but wasn't able to get any further in sorting the arrays..

```sh
function sort_by {
    # for each hash in the given array
    get_stdin # (custom func, sets $STDIN)
    for hash in ${STDIN[@]}
    do
      # get the hash keys
      hash_keys="$(eval "echo \${!$hash[@]}")"
      # for each key
      for hashkey in $hash_keys
      do
        # reset
        return_the_array=false
        # if $hashkey matches the key given
        if [ "$hashkey" = "$1" ];then
          # check the value of this one if highest/lowest
          # (compared to previous ones)
          # and then return if yes/mo (asc/desc)
        fi
        # if $return_the_array = true, then we found the right key and
        # it's higher/lower
        if [ "$return_the_array" = true ];then
          # do stuff
        fi
      done
    done
}
```

Comment: It would be way easier to just store the data as newline separated csv file. Then sorting is a simple `sort`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Bash 4.3 or newer, you can use namerefs for this, as follows:

```
sort_by() {
    local arr field sort_params elem
    declare -n arr=$1
    field=$2

    # Build array with sort parameters
    [[ $3 == 'desc' ]] && sort_params+=('-r')
    [[ $field == 'age' ]] && sort_params+=('-n')

    # Schwartzian transform
    for elem in "${arr[@]}"; do
        declare -n ref=$elem
        printf '%s\t%s\n' "${ref["$field"]}" "$elem"
    done | sort "${sort_params[@]}" | cut -f2
}

declare -A assoc1=([name]=aaa [age]=20)
declare -A assoc2=([name]=bbb [age]=40)
declare -A assoc3=([name]=ccc [age]=25)
indexed_array=(assoc1 assoc2 assoc3)

readarray -t byage < <(sort_by indexed_array age desc)
declare -p byage

readarray -t byname < <(sort_by indexed_array name asc)
declare -p byname
```

The calling syntax is a bit different:

```
sort_by ARRAYNAME FIELD SORTORDER
```

and the output is one element per line, so to read it back into an array, we have to use something like `readarray` (see examples at the end).

First, we use a nameref to assign the arrayname to `arr`:

```
declare -n arr=$1
```

`arr` now behaves as if it were the actual array.

Then, we build an array with the parameters for `sort`: if the third parameter is `desc`, we use `-r`, and if the field is `age`, we use `-n`. This could be made a bit smarter and check if the field contains numeric values or not, and set `-n` accordingly.

We then iterate over the elements of `arr`, the elements of which are the names of the associative arrays. In the loop, we assign the names to `ref`:

```
declare -n ref=$elem
```

`ref` now behaves like the actual associative array.

To sort, we use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) (decorate – sort – undecorate) by printing lines with the chosen field name and then the array name; for example, for `age`, we'd get

```
20      assoc1
40      assoc2
25      assoc3
```

This is piped to `sort` with the proper parameters, and with `cut -f2` we remove the sort field again.

The output for the examples looks like this:

```
declare -a byage=([0]="assoc2" [1]="assoc3" [2]="assoc1")
declare -a byname=([0]="assoc1" [1]="assoc2" [2]="assoc3")
```

Notice that `declare -n` declares local parameters in the function, so they don't pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, I am using a modified version of the accepted answer:

```sh
function sort_by {
    local field sort_params elem
    field=$1
    # Build array with sort parameters
    [[ $2 == 'desc' ]] && sort_params+=('-r')
    [[ $field == 'age' ]] && sort_params+=('-n')
    # Schwartzian transform, 
    # get piped array contents from $(cat)
    while read -r elem; do
        declare -n ref=$elem
        printf '%s\t%s\n' "${ref["$field"]}" "$elem"
    done | sort "${sort_params[@]}" | cut -f2 | tr '\n' ' '
}
```

The difference between this function and the accepted answer, is that this function above expects to receive the **contents** of the indexed array as **piped input**, rather than taking the **array name** as the **first parameter**..

Therefore, my function can be called like so:

```sh
echo ${someIndexedArray[@]} | sort_by 'age' 'desc'
```

(And this func outputs everything on the same line, as opposed to newlines)

The benefit of this (for me) is that it now works in the CMS I am using, and also ,the `sort_by` function does not need to know the name of the array - which would not be passed by the CMS.

Comment: Instead of `for elem in $(cat)`, I'd do `while read -r elem`.

Comment: ah, I see... ok thanks, that works, and without starting sub-shell.. nice, cheers.. have edited the code above